# fixed elements break when scrolling during transition in WebKit

Tags: jquery, html, css

The fixed element scrolls with you and then reappears in the correct spot only in Webkit.
Its fine on Firefox.

**JS:**

```
 var num = 50; //number of pixels before modifying styles

 $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
         $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
     } else {
         $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
     }
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu"><h1> Amigas </h1></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
background: #345;
color: #FFF;
z-index: 999;
padding: .5em;
position: absolute;
top: 47px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: What is "num" in the jquery code?

Comment: Forgot something var edited the question

Comment: What do you mean by "correct spot"? I just tried that in both Chrome and Firefox and couldn't see a problem.

Comment: in Chrome it has this hard effect while in firefox its smooth while scrolling

Comment: By the way, you need to change your title and question cause the real question that you ask is completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

That is specific feature of the browsers. Firefox started to use smooth scrolling with new versions by default. In Chrome, you need to enable it yourself or you can use plugins. To enable it, you can open chrome://flags/ page and enable the "Smooth Scrolling" option. Or you can use something like "Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller" plugin for more options.